# How to resolve: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently taking a Udemy class to learn Android development with Kotlin.  At the end of the last two exercises I'm running into the following compile issues:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class androidx.databinding.BaseObservable found in modules databinding-runtime-8.2.1-runtime (androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.1) and library-3.2.0-alpha11-runtime (androidx.databinding:library:3.2.0-alpha11)
> Duplicate class androidx.databinding.BaseObservableField found in modules databinding-runtime-8.2.1-runtime (androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.1) and library-3.2.0-alpha11-runtime (androidx.databinding:library:3.2.0-alpha11)
> Duplicate class androidx.databinding.BaseObservableField$DependencyCallback found in modules databinding-runtime-8.2.1-runtime (androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.1) and library-3.2.0-alpha11-runtime (androidx.databinding:library:3.2.0-alpha11)
> Duplicate class androidx.databinding.Bindable found in modules baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha11 (androidx.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha11) and databinding-common-8.2.1 (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:8.2.1)
> ...
> ...
> ...

And it goes on forever...

The instructor in the class had a similar issue but updated the build.gradle.kts for the following:

Update to the following....

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

From .... 

 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```

They said it was from the use of the plugin: id("kotlin-kapt")

Can someone help me out?  There is a sea of information on this but I was hoping someone might have some insight.